# Select different nodes with different depths in one xpath

Tags: html, xpath

```
<div>
  <p>a</p>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <other-tags></other-tags>
<div>
```

I would like to select `p` and `li` tags in the above example.

I can do it using `//div/p|//div/ul/li`, but is it possible to achieve the same without `|`, in other words, not repeating `//div`. I tried `//div/*[self::p or self::ul/li]`, but it selected `p` and `ul` tags.

Comment: What you're looking for is `//div/(p | ul/li)` , but it's not available in XPath 1.0. You can also try `//div/*[self::p or self::ul]/descendant-or-self::*[self::p or self::li]`, but it looks overcomplicated and I'm not sure that it won't match undesirable nodes

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
//*[self::p or self::li]
```

will select all `p` and `li` elements in the document.

This XPath,

```
//div[@id="i1"]//*[self::p or self::li]
```

will select all `p` and `li` elements under the targeted `div` element(s).

Comment: I only want `div->p` and `div->ul->li`, not all `p` and `li`, for example: `div->div->p`

Comment: Your requirements are getting to be so convoluted that I suspect you have a XY-Problem on your hands.  If the actual XPath for which you're allowing `//div` to serve as a proxy has a fixed depth, then you can adapt the XPath's in the answer with `[count(ancestor::*) = ` *depth* `]` predicates on each of the `self::` parts.   However, I get the feeling that answer to your actual problem has been swept away with your simplification or lost due to wrong assumptions about the best approach.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

All you should do is use `//p|//li`. Also, it helps to research stuff ***`before`*** posting it on StackOverflow, as I found this information [here](https://help.parsehub.com/hc/en-us/articles/220618167-Using-XPath-to-select-elements). Why are you trying to avoid using `|` in your XPath?

Comment: Whoops, typo! Fixed now

Comment: Oh, sorry. I just found what I thought was the best.

Comment: Because the `//div` part in my case is very very long and I thought it might be faster because it wouldn't search the same path twice. BTW, I only want those `p` and `ul/li` are the direct children of `//div`, not all children.